# Ubuntu on external drive. The order of boot devices constantly changes

Tags: boot, uefi

After many tries, I was able to create a fully bootable and portable Ubuntu system on an external drive. It works great, but there is one thing that bothers me.

The idea was that when I connect an external drive with Ubuntu, the PC boots Ubuntu, and when there is no external drive, the PC boots Windows 11.
But it only happens when I go to UEFI and change the boot device order, set the ones from Ubuntu first. After disconnecting the Ubuntu disk, its boot device disappears from UEFI. When I reconnect the drive, the boot device goes back to the UEFI boot order, BUT AS A SECOND AFTER WIN 11. So every time I unplug my Ubuntu drive, plug it back in and want to boot it, I have to go into UEFI to change the boot order and restart the PC.

The question is: is it possible to avoid this UEFI setting when I want to run my Ubuntu? To have external drive constantly plugged in is not the answer.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: UEFI forgets UEFI boot entry for any device that is unplugged. You do not need to change boot order, just from UEFI boot menu boot the external drive. That should boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is a copy of shimx64.efi and is how you boot installer from live USB.